# Proper way of starting virtual process

Tags: windows, appv

With app-v 5.1 sequencer, i packaged files in 
`[{AppVPackageDrive}]\folder1\folder2\app.exe`

and have put .appv package in network share 
`\\192.168.0.2\…\package.appv`

Now, from client machine i want to run this app-v package.

This is what i did in powershell as Administrator:

```
$package = Add-AppvClientPackage -Path \\192.168.0.2\…\package.appv
Publish-AppvClientPackage $package
```

And this is what i did as normal user:

```
$p = Get-AppvClientPackage Package
Start-AppvVirtualProcess -AppvClientObject $p
```

Now the powershell asks me to:

`Supply values for the following parameters:
FilePath:`

What should i enter?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to specify which EXE from that package (or outside the package) you want to launch. Get-AppvClientPackage returns only the package object.

Here is the doc on launching a virtual process:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2848278/how-to-launch-processes-inside-the-app-v-5-0-virtualized-environment